# battery percentage is displayed wrongly

Tags: laptop, battery

I recently replaced a new battery, the battery now does not show low battery percentage warnings and just abruptly turns off the computer when the charge is about 20%, and  when I turn it back on, it starts from 0% and I recognize the battery was all drained out.

Why is this wrong percentage being read in my new battery? Is this a calibration problem or I should exchange the battery because it is damaged? If this is a calibration problem, are there ways to solve this?

Comment: The battery has a firmware with S/n and some info such as capacity. The charge level is detected by the charge chip. If it's a battery from Aliexpress or similar they often come with very bad quality battery cells that don't keep charge and the output current is lower that expected. That's why charge chip can detect that charge level incorrectly. Please use BatteryInfoView https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html to read physical state info about your battery as well as firmware. This may give you a better insight of it's state.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest returning it as the first course of action. A new battery should charge well and hold the charge for a couple of hours at least. It takes 2 or 3 years of constant use to wear a battery down to about 1/2 capacity.

So return it for exchange or refund.

2. If you wish to try to re-calibrate, use the Battery Management app that came pre-loaded. You should only use the App that came with the machine to do a re-calibration.

The generalized steps are (a) charge to full; (b) allow to discharge to computer turning off ; (c) allow computer to sit for an hour or so ; turn on a re-charge.

Make sure you have a re-calibration setup in your Battery App. If no battery app, perhaps just return the battery.

Comment: battery app? you mean that comes with the OS or .... does a battery have a driver or something? I'm using linux , I don't see such apps in the OS

Comment: A Battery App should come with the computer as set up by the manufacturer.  Dell, Lenovo, and I think HP have these. Other manufacturers do as well.  If you do not see one, then it may not be there and so just return the battery for refund / exchange.

Comment: my laptop is of dell, do you mean in the BIOS settings? otherwise how would hardware manufactures would put it on the PC? should the app be there after OS is booter or in the BIOS?

Comment: Dell has a battery App but you need to look at the Dell Support site for a Linux version. Dell batteries can be re-calibrated. I posted the general steps but look on the Dell Support site for their re-calibration document. They have one. The app is not in the BIOS.

Comment: their community has the same charge/discharge routine: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/calibrate-laptop-battery/td-p/4536735 , but nowhere do they list any calibration app

Comment: It may be bundled with a different name. Mine is called Vantage.  You would need to research this if you think it is of value. Your battery appears to be defective.

Comment: you mean the app is named for different laptop models? What should I be searching for?

Comment: You need to research the Dell site for this. My machines are Lenovo and the Lenovo docs tell me this information.